# Making the folded corners in tikzposter smaller

Tags: tikzposter

I am using tikzposter with the standard wave theme.

I would like to make the folded corners a bit smaller (or even keep the theme but switch to other box headings such as those from Envelope, but I understand it's not easy to mix styles, so just making folds smaller would help as they are now covering text.

```
\documentclass[a0paper, landscape, 24pt, margin=0mm,
  innermargin=15mm, colspace=10mm, subcolspace=8mm,
  blockverticalspace=15mm]{tikzposter}
\usetheme{Wave} % Default, Rays, Basic, Simple, Envelope, Wave, Board, Autumn, and Desert.
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{4cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1mm}
\usepackage{authblk} %add the below lines to tweek so no extra vertical space appears
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\maketitle{\AB@maketitle} % revert \maketitle to its old definition
\makeatother
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\Large} % set font for affiliations
\title{Test title} 
\author[1]{Author}
\affil[1]{Test}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{columns}
\column{.65}
\block{}{
\lipsum{20}
}
\column{.35}
\block{}{
\lipsum{30}
}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

See my issue:

[image]

Comment: You *can* modify it by copying the code `\defineblockstyle{Corner}{...}` from `tikzposterBlockstyles.tex` to the preamble of your poster, and adjusting some of the hardcoded distances there. You need to modify the pahts in `\def \border{ ... }` and `\def \corner{ ($(blocktitle.north east)-(0,6)$) ...`. Playing with these, I could make the corners smaller. However, I refrain from posting my code here because (a) it is ugly and (b) I am afraid that it will trigger tons of follow-up questions. IMHO the whole package would need to be rewritten without hardcoded stuff but pgf keys.